# decimal to hexadecimal unit convertion

Tags: c

I have the next code that converts an decimal unit to an hexadecimal.If i introduce the number 4095 for example, it returns the FFF hexadecimal,but the problem is that i want the number to be printed in a 2 byte format like this(with zeros on the left):

4095 -> 0FFF,
33   -> 0021

i know that there are simpler ways to do this like:

```
int number = 4095
printf("%04x",number);
```

but i want to do the conversions and the 2 byte format by myself,but i dont know how to do the zero's on the left procedure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char Hexadecimal(int rest);

int main()
{
    char num_hex,*x,c[2],;
    int number = 4095,d,rest;
    x = calloc(12,sizeof(char));
    for(d = number;d > 0;d/=16)
    {
        rest = d % 16;
        num_hex = Hexadecimal(rest);
        sprintf(c,"%c",num_hex);
        strcat(x,c);
    }
    strrev(x);
    printf("[%s]\n",x);
    return 0;
}

char Hexadecimal(int rest)
{
    char letter;
    switch(rest)
    {
        case 10:
           letter = 'A';
           break;
        case 11:
           letter = 'B';
           break;
        case 12:
           letter = 'C';
           break;
        case 13:
           letter = 'D';
           break;
        case 14:
           letter = 'E';
           break;
        case 15:
           letter = 'F';
           break;
        default:
           letter = '0' + rest;
    }
    return letter;
}
```

Comment: You function `Hexadecimal` can be done in one line i.e. `return "0123456789ABCDEF"[rest];`

Comment: `sprintf(c,"%c",num_hex);` is equivalent to: `*c=num_hex;c[1]=0;`

Comment: Because you want to always print exactly 4 digits, you can begin filling the string from the end, so that you don't need to reverse it. At the moment, you begin filling from the front, stop when the number is over (**not when you processed 4 digits**), and then reverse.

Comment: just do nibble by nibble, no need to divide by 16 because each hexadecimal digit corresponds to exactly 4 bits

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char const  Hexadecimal[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

int main()
{
    char num_hex,*x,c[2],;
    int number = 4095,d,rest;
    x = calloc(12,sizeof(char));
    for(d = number;d > 0;d/=16)
    {
        rest = d % 16;
        num_hex = Hexadecimal[rest];
        sprintf(c,"%c",num_hex);
        strcat(x,c);
    }
    strrev(x);
    printf("[%s]\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is special about 12? `int` could be 2,4,8, etc. bytes?

Comment: @chux I just copied the same code and changed the part of main question (hexadecimal) , I'd use `x=calloc(sizeof(int), sizeof(char));` I guess! correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Sorry.  Yes, I now see 12 came from the OP's 12. `x=calloc(sizeof(int), sizeof(char));` is good in that you are attempting to scale to the `int` size, but it is likely too small.  Too bad there is not a define in `<limits.h>`.  I've used `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3 +3` from time to time for decimal.  Maybe `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/4 +4` for hex.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to think of these problems in terms of binary arithmetic.

Here's an implementation that uses binary math and no standard library functions. It's written in a general way, so you could replace `short` with `int` or `long` and get a similarly correct result (as long as you replace the `short` type everywhere in the function with your desired type).

```
char* shortToHex(short value)
{
    static char tmp[(sizeof(short)*2)+3] = "0x";
    const char* hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    int i = sizeof(short);

    while(i > 0)
    {
        i--;
        char most_significant_nibble = (value >> (i * 8 + 4)) & 0xF;
        char least_significant_nibble = (value >> (i * 8)) & 0xF;
        tmp[2 + (sizeof(short)-i-1) * 2] = hex[most_significant_nibble];
        tmp[2 + (sizeof(short)-i-1) * 2 + 1] = hex[least_significant_nibble];
    }

    tmp[(sizeof(short)*2)+2] = 0;

    return tmp;
}
```

Let me explain line-by-line so you understand.

```
    static char tmp[(sizeof(short)*2)+3] = "0x";
```

We need a buffer large enough to hold the amount of nibbles in a short (16 bits == 2 bytes == 4 characters, so two per byte in general) plus a `'\0'` terminator, plus the `"0x"` string.

```
    const char* hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

We need to be able to grab a hexadecimal character based on an array index.

```
    while(i > 0)
    {
        i--;
        ...
    }
```

We need a loop counter that counts down from the number of bytes in a short. We're going to loop starting at the most significant byte, to build up the string left-to-right.

```
        char most_significant_nibble = (value >> (i * 8 + 4)) & 0xF;
        char least_significant_nibble = (value >> (i * 8)) & 0xF;
        tmp[2 + (sizeof(short)-i-1) * 2] = hex[most_significant_nibble];
        tmp[2 + (sizeof(short)-i-1) * 2 + 1] = hex[least_significant_nibble];
```

We're going to shift the bits in the input `value` to the right, so that the desired bits are in the least-significant nibble of a temporary character. We determine how many bits to shift by multiplying the index (in the case of a 16-bit short, `i` would start out being `1` since we decremented it, so we'll have `1 * 8 + 4` the first time through the loop, and shift 12 bits to the right, leaving us with the most significant nibble in the short. The second line would shift 8 bits to the right and grab the second nibble. (and so on) The `& 0xF` portion ensures that whatever 4-bit value we have shifted furthest to the right is the only value in the temporary `char`.

Then we take those temporary values and set them into the `tmp` array at the appropriate place. (the math is a little tricky since our index as at the most significant - highest - byte of the value, but we want to place the character at the lowest point in the `tmp` value.)

```
    tmp[(sizeof(short)*2)+2] = 0;

    return tmp;
```

Lastly, we terminate the `tmp` string with a `'\0'` and return it.